# Sum of matrix elements on a parallel region resulting on wrong answers on OpenMP

Tags: c, gcc, parallel-processing, openmp

I was doing an activity at my university that requires to populate a matrix of [2000][2000] elements and then calculate the sum of all elements that are multiples of 5 in a parallel way.

At first I tried using a 5 x 5 matrix, I did a parcial sum (sumP) of the elements and them I added all the elements on a variable called Sum into a critical region.

On my university computer the parcial sum was receiving thrash values (like 36501) when the values must be lower than 100; I noted that it only happend on the [0][i] (line zero) of the matrix.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <omp.h>

#define N 5


int main() {
    int i, j, k, l;
    int sum = 0;
    int sumP = 0;
    int A[N][N]; 
    printf("sumP : %i\n", sumP );
    printf("sum: %i\n", sum);
    #pragma omp parallel shared (A) private (i, j)
    {
        #pragma omp for
        for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
            for(j = 0; j < N; j++){
            A[i][j] = i%5;
            printf("Number: %i, pos[%i][%i]\n", A[i][j], i, j);
            }
        }
    }

    #pragma omp parallel shared(A, sum) private (k, l, sumP)
    {               
        #pragma omp for
        for (k = 0; k < N; k++) {
            for (l = 0; l < N; l++){
                if (A[l][k] % 5 == 0 && A[l][k] != 0){
                sumP = sumP + A[k][l];
                printf("numero: %i, pos [%i],[%i] sumP: %i\n", A[k][l], k, l, sumP);
                }
            }   
        }
        #pragma omp critical
        sum += sumP;

    }
        //printf("sumP: %i\n", sumP);
        printf("sum: %i\n", sum);

    return (0);
}
```

I tested it declaring the value of sumP to 0 between the "for" statemants, and it worked:

```
#pragma omp parallel shared(A, soma) private (k, l, somap2)
    {               
        #pragma omp for
        for (k = 0; k < N; k++) {
                        sumP = 0;
            for (l = 0; l < N; l++){
```

when I tested it home it worked without having to declare the sumP as 0 (on the parcial sum "sumP"), like I did above, but now the final Sum result is not correct...

Comment: what would be the value of `sumP` in each parallel worker ?

Comment: I did a parcial sum on each for thread and than a final sum at the end

Comment: could you `printf` `sumP` before being summed in `soma` that could probably explain your issue

Comment: Show where `sum` is change in your code.

Comment: Also the code as it is is non compilable

Comment: sorry, forgot to translat the soma to sum variable. On the original code I used the variables in portuguese, I translated it to post here, but forgot the sum, I edited it and now its the same way as my code.

Comment: in this teste none of the numbers is multiple of 5 and the result is -3

sumP : 0
sum: 0
Number: 0, pos[0][0]
Number: 0, pos[0][1]
Number: 0, pos[0][2]
Number: 0, pos[0][3]
Number: 0, pos[0][4]
Number: 1, pos[1][0]
Number: 1, pos[1][1]
Number: 1, pos[1][2]
Number: 1, pos[1][3]
Number: 1, pos[1][4]
Number: 2, pos[2][0]
Number: 2, pos[2][1]
Number: 2, pos[2][2]
Number: 2, pos[2][3]
Number: 2, pos[2][4]
Number: 3, pos[3][0]
[...] (supressed part of the result)
sum: -3

Comment: removing the if statement that check if the number is multiple of 5 and doing a 3x3 matrix I got:

Number: 0, pos[0][0]
Number: 0, pos[0][1]
Number: 0, pos[0][2]
Number: 1, pos[1][0]
Number: 1, pos[1][1]
Number: 1, pos[1][2]
Number: 2, pos[2][0]
Number: 2, pos[2][1]
Number: 2, pos[2][2]
numero: 1, pos [1],[0] sumP: 0
numero: 1, pos [1],[1] sumP: 1
numero: 1, pos [1],[2] sumP: 2
numero: 0, pos [0],[0] sumP: 0
numero: 0, pos [0],[1] sumP: 0
numero: 0, pos [0],[2] sumP: 0
numero: 2, pos [2],[0] sumP: 1
numero: 2, pos [2],[1] sumP: 3
numero: 2, pos [2],[2] sumP: 5
sum: 6

Comment: Maybe if you would describe what your sum loop should be doing compared to what you can trace by hand

Comment: so your condition is `if A[i][j] is a multiple of 5 and not 0` ? And consider the way you are populating your first loop

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You observe this behavior because `private` variables in OpenMP are uninitialized. To be precise, they are initialized as if you would have a local variable without an explicit initialization. Which means it is undefined what value they have initially. You observe different behavior on different systems because some combinations of compiler, options, and OS use this "undefined" differently. Your code is incorrect in any case, even if it sometimes produces the correct result.

Now you can do this setting to zero as you tried out. However, I would generally suggest to instead **declare variables as local as possible**. This makes reasoning about the (parallel) code much easier, and you can omit the "private/shared" declarations. So your code would look like this:

```
#pragma omp parallel
{
    int sumP = 0;
    #pragma omp for
    for (int k = 0; k < N; k++) {
        for (int l = 0; l < N; l++) {
            if (A[l][k] % 5 == 0 && A[l][k] != 0) {
                sumP = sumP + A[k][l];
                printf("numero: %i, pos [%i],[%i] sumP: %i\n", A[k][l], k, l, sumP);
            }
        }   
    }
    #pragma omp critical
    sum += sumP;
}
```

In addition to that, there is another way to drastically simplify this code by using a reduction:

```
#pragma omp parallel for reduction(+:sum)
for (int k = 0; k < N; k++) {
    for (int l = 0; l < N; l++) {
        if (A[l][k] % 5 == 0 && A[l][k] != 0) {
            sum += A[k][l];
        }
    }   
}
```

The compiler will basically do the same thing for you (but better) and the code is much cleaner.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. My professor teached us this way, but using a Vector instead of a matrix. Is there any difference between using a nested for and a non nested for in omp for? Because when we tried the non nested for it worked. My professor teached that we needed to use a private on sumP to avoid that the other threads access the provisory sum and to avoid a data concurrency.

Comment: By "this way" I meant the way I did

Comment: `#pragma omp parallel for` ist really just a shorthand for `#pragma omp parallel` and `#pragma omp for`. If you don't use `reduction`, you need the separate pragmas to have space for the local sum initialization.

Answer (score 0):

Considering that your code would spend most of its time dealing with I/O it would be a good idea to comment the `printf`

But as I understand `sumP` should contain the partial sum of your inner loop

Pragmas have been compressed for readability

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <omp.h>

#define N 1000


int main() {
    int i, j;
    int sum = 0;
    int sumP = 0;
    int A[N][N]; // will cause segfault with large N
    printf("sumP : %i\n", sumP );
    printf("sum: %i\n", sum);
    #pragma omp parallel for shared (A) private (i, j)
    for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        for(j = 0; j < N; j++){
            A[i][j] = i%5; // populate array with numbers in [0,1,2,3,4]
            //printf("Number: %i, pos[%i][%i]\n", A[i][j], i, j);
        }
    }

    #pragma omp parallel for shared(A) private (i, j, sumP) reduction(+: sum)
    for (i = 0; i< N; i++) { // outer (parallel)loop 
        sumP = 0; // initialize partial sum
        for (j = 0; j < N; j++){ // inner sequential loop
            //if (A[i][j] % 5 == 0 && A[i][j] != 0){ // Explain this condition 
                sumP += A[i][j];
                //printf("numero: %i, pos [%i],[%i] sumP: %i\n", A[i][j], i, j, sumP);
            //}
        }
        //printf("sumP: %i\n", sumP);
        sum += sumP; // add partial sum
    }

    //printf("sumP: %i\n", sumP);
    printf("sum: %i\n", sum);

    return (0);
}
```